# Empty interior lack of minima

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose that $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, and satsifies

- $U$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^d$,
- U has empty interior,

Then is it possible that
$$
\inf_{x \in U} f(x) >\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} f(x),
$$
for some (fixed) lsc function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always afraid of confusing lsc and usc, but what about $d=1$ and $U=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f(x) =1$ for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Yes this is lsc.

Comment: Cool, I came up with a slightly reduced version of this concentrated at a single point in  $\mathbb{R}^d-U$.  Thanks :)